# XNA 3.5 Firing a tank cannon

Tags: c#, xna

I have a 2D image of a tanks body (top down) that can be moved left-right across the screen.
On top, there's a second image of the tanks turret. This turret can be rotated across the screen edge following the users mouse movement along the Y axis.

When the user presses'Enter' a bullet appears and moves across the screen at the angle of the turret. However, whilst the angle is fine, the bullet's position seems to vary a lot. At times, it sites where it should (in the centre of the cannon) however, as you move the mouse it seems to get offsetted.

---

Edit: For some strange reason, my pictures don't seem to be showing up - so here is a direct link: http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/7093/khte.png

Edited Code:

```
Tank Fire
     if (keyBoardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
                {
                    shell.Initialize(rotation, new Vector2(location.X + 25, location.Y - 15));
                    shell.makeAlive();
                }
```

(It is initialized with the location of the tank (+25, -25) so it appears at the end of the turrent. having this set at the tanks location (shell.Initialize(rotation, location);) seems to make no difference to the offset.)

Bullet/Shell:

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (alive)
        {
            movement.X -= speed * (float)Math.Cos(rotation);
            movement.Y -= speed * (float)Math.Sin(rotation);

            location.X += (int)movement.X;
            location.Y += (int)movement.Y;
        }
    }


    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        if (alive)
        {
            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteBlendMode.AlphaBlend);
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, location, null, Color.White, rotation - MathHelper.PiOver2, new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2), 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't get the bullets positioned where the turret is?  does the mouse cause them to move after you've fired them, or before you've fired them?

Comment: Hi, please see my update. I've taken a screenshot of where the bullet is (marked in black) and where I want it (marked in yellow)
thanks

Comment: Have you thought about just spawning the bullet right on top of the tank and then just displacing it during your update loop if it hasn't fired yet?

Comment: My issue is that I can't get the positioning of the bullet right. It always seems to be offsetted and sits a long way in front of the tank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get your bullet to rotate about your tank, than I personally draw the bullet on top of the tank do the exact same thing that you do after you've fired your bullet(but with a greater magnitude) to displace it,

But if you want to use the `origin` parameter of `SpriteBatch.Draw`, than I'd imagine that it would look something like this:

given the following datapoints:

```
this.origin = new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2);
tank.origin = new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2);

// and this is what you'd pass into your sprite-batch.draw method
originToDraw = (tank.position + tank.origin)-(this.position + this.origin)
```

And you also have to initialize your bullet's position to the appropriate starting point Since I don't actually know where rotation comes from, I can't know for sure, but if it's the angle between your tank and the mouse, than I'd imagine it'd be the following

```
this.startingPosition = tank.position + tank.origin - this.origin
```

Comment: Hi,
The idea was to rotate it around the origin of the turrent so that it would be drawn at the end of the turrent...
I've edited the code now and added a new picture. It's still not lined up...

Answer (score 0):

I asume that `shell` is a `Bullet` instance if yes your problem is the origin in `Bullet` class. It should have set this value in `LoadTextures` method

```
public void LoadTextures(Texture2D texture)
{
    this.texture = texture;
    this.origin = new Vector2(texture.Width, texture.Height);
}
```

And a little extra in `Bullet.Draw` method:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, location, null, Color.White, rotation - 1.5f, origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

change  1.5f to `MathHelper.PiOver2` it is more accure when you want to rotate something 90 degrees

Comment: Hi,
I've made that change, thanks for that.
and yes, bullet=shell, sorry I'll make that less confusing!
Code update now though

Answer (score 0):

You have a nasty roundoff problem here.

You compute the velocity in floating point but switch to integers for the bullet's location.  The problem is that while *ON AVERAGE* the errors even out any given bullet is going to either round up or round down every time.

Lets take an extreme case:  The bullet is fired 25 degrees off the vertical axis and it's moving at two pixels per update cycle.  Strangely enough the bullet flies directly down the axis.

Or an even more extreme case.  The speed is 1/3 pixel per cycle.  The bullet stands still.